# How to change Docker Image location on Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, docker

I have searched everywhere and all solutions are mostly outdated. I want to either change the whole docker dir from C Drive to D drive or only image from C to D. Because I have less space on C drive.
I am currently using Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Have you tried update your virtual machine, which is created by Docker install?

Comment: Also when I open Docker setup, I see option Disk Image location there. Which version of Docker you have?